# Adding module to boot module list

Tags: kernel

What is the exact command for adding `b43` module to the startup module list?

I have tried adding `b43` to the end of `/etc/modules` and receive a message of access denied. In order to have wireless turn after reboot I have to use command `sudo modprobe b43`.

Answer (score 2):

You must open `modules` with `root` permissions

```
gksu gedit /etc/modules
```

Write your password (nothing will appear in terminal) and hit Enter.

Write here `g43`. That should be all you need.

Probably not required but if it needs special options/parameters:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/g43.conf
```

Add here any options.

Don't forget to save (Ctrl+S).

Comment: I must be dumb as a post, still can't add b43 module in such a way as to have wireless turn on at boot up. Still have to use command (sudo modprobe b43) to load driver after boot to get wireless. Never used ubuntu before, this all new to me, and seem to have more than usual newbe problems.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user272695 have you followed the instructions?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel modules can use two different methods of automatic loading:

**/etc/modules.conf**; Load the modules before the rest of the services. Refer to [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man5/modules.conf.5.html) or typing `man 5 modules.conf` for more help. Sample `modules.conf`:

```
# modules.conf - configuration file for loading kernel modules
...
b43
...
```

**/etc/rc.local**: Using this method loads the modules after all other services are started, Sample `rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
...
/sbin/modprobe b4
...
exit 0
```